# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 started to crash immediately after statup

Tags: windows-7, crash, visual-studio-2015, process-monitor

Recently, my VS2015 has started to crash immediately after starting up. The `ActivityLog.xml` has a limited info: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D2799D1EAD5F9578!712404&authkey=!AL8QhGRUdZdRsaU&ithint=file%2cxlsx

And Process Monitor has tons of errors as well: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D2799D1EAD5F9578!712405&authkey=!AIBrfuxAkbo64H0&ithint=file%2cxlsx

Thing is, it worked yesterday after a few reboots. I kept that instance ON but laptop rebooted just now due to corporate updates. I'm on Windows 7 x64 Enterprise. This is a corporate environment. The `My Documents` folder is network based and being synced offline. I cannot change that. I also have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Premium installed and that stopped working as well. It crashes with in a similar fashion with almost same ActivityLog.xml.

I have tried cleaning all temp directories. I have tried clearing the componentcache folder for VS2015. I tried running in safe mode and when it was running today, I uninstalled almost all the extensions. I did try the reset and setup command-line. That didn't help either.

I see from the Process Monitor log that there are many FILE/PATH errors.

Can anyone help?

**Update**

Dump text: https://pastebin.com/UbqYhY6s
Dump file: https://db.tt/SktHWvpe

**Update**
The issue went away for exactly one week and now it is back but this time the dumps are being generated and I loaded a latest one in *WinDbg* and did the **!analyze -v** command. I've updated/replaced the result in the above PasteBin.

Comment: capture a crash dump of VS (import this file: dropbox.com/s/kmtkd1h7ans24v5/WER_VS_full.reg?dl=0 to configure WER to generate a dump: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx). After VS crashes, you can see a dmp in C:\localdumps, now import this reg to stop dmp creation: dropbox.com/s/vhj02wpza12bvwj/WER_VS_full_uninstall.reg?dl=0). Open the dmp in Windbg.exe (part of Windows SDK/Debugging Tools), setup symbols (support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) and run **!analyze -v**. Now look if you can see at which part VS crashes.

Comment: And if there is no dump being created? Does that indicate VS is shutting down instead of crashing? I double checked the reg file and confirmed the entry as well.

Comment: look in the registry if the entry was added. Some Av suites block the import. Also the Windows Error reporting service must be running. if this still fails, use procdump from Microsoft. download the tool, open a cmd as admin in this folder and run **procdump -ma -i C:\localdumps**. If applications crash now, procdump creates dumps.

Comment: I confirmed the entry. There are many others there as well. But VS is crashing and no new file is being generated. After searching, I did stumbled into this `D:\Users\6587\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_devenv.exe_b68758229f01270a8becdf77ab9cb8d23d19c9_08b66123` and as per *Search Everything*, this is a dump from 30-May. So I'm gonna spend some time now...

Comment: try procdump. open this dmp in windbg, setup the symbols and run **!analyze -v**

Comment: Did a a very long tiring for-each exp: !analyze -v. Huge log so pasted @ pastebin

Comment: I'm trying to fix *ntdll.dll* as it is repeatedly highlighted in the analyzed log. `sfc /scannow` only detects some file called `diskmgt.CHM` and fixes it and if I run again, the same `diskmgt.CHM` is found and fixed. I cannot run the `RegSvr32` on *ntdll.dll* either: The module "C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Make sure that "C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

Comment: No luck. **One simply does not try to fix *ntdll.dll***

Comment: the ntdll.dll is fine. open the last dump again and run the commands posted after STACK_COMMAND ** .ecxr ; kb ; dps 61bf12c ; kb**

Comment: i was not able to generate a stack. I tried to run devenv through WinDbg

Comment: try procdump to generate dumps if the WER trick fails

Comment: procdump had the same issue. It started listening for crashes and spikes using the command in above comments but VS kept crashing and it sensed nothing. No dumps.

Comment: I executed `.ecxr ; kb ; dps 61bf12c ; kb` after each exception while running through WinDbg and update the question above

Comment: this dps 61bf12c chanegs. look each time what WIndbg suggests at **STACK_COMMAND** and run this command. you have a NX fault everytime in the finalizer. try safemode and remove 3rd party extensions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40694/discussion-between-doomerdgr8-and-magicandre1981).