# Visual Studio 2015 crashes on startup

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

my Visual Studio 2015 keeps crashing and I cannot find out why.

Yesterday I wanted to install the Python Tools March 2016. This included the update 2 for VS2015. After installation Visual Studio started crashing on startup. The splash screen appears, then the white main window which immediately crashes.

I reinstalled VS2015 but it did not help. Installing VS2015.2 did not work, I had to install Visual Studio without updates.

I tried executing VS2015 with /log. The ActivityLog.xml does not contain any errors. It basically just says that it loaded a lot of packages and then just exited:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ActivityLog.xsl"?>
<activity>
  <entry>
    <record>1</record>
    <time>2016/06/24 11:09:41.257</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 version: 14.0.23107.0</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2</record>
    <time>2016/06/24 11:09:41.257</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Creating PkgDefCacheNonVolatile</description>
  </entry>
  ...
  <entry>
    <record>127</record>
    <time>2016/06/24 11:10:02.906</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Global Search Package]</description>
    <guid>{18333854-D2FF-44A3-98D8-40501B914D7D}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>128</record>
    <time>2016/06/24 11:10:02.906</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Global Search Package]</description>
    <guid>{18333854-D2FF-44A3-98D8-40501B914D7D}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>129</record>
    <time>2016/06/24 11:10:02.985</time>
    <type></type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Destroying Main Window</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>130</record>
    <time>2016/06/24 11:10:03.110</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>AppId stopped registry detouring</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>131</record>
    <time>2016/06/24 11:10:03.110</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Shutting down pkgdef registry</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>132</record>
    <time>2016/06/24 11:10:03.110</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Released pkgdef cache usage tracker</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>133</record>
    <time>2016/06/24 11:10:03.110</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef registry shutdown complete</description>
  </entry>
</activity>
```

When Visual Studio crashes Windows gives me the option to "debug". When I do this and select my VS2013 it says `NullReferenceException` in `PresentationFramework.dll` but not much more.

Then I tried to follow the advice from [Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 started to crash immediately after statup](https://superuser.com/questions/1083125/visual-studio-2015-update-2-started-to-crash-immediately-after-statup#comment1532366_1083125). I got a core dump. Windbg tells me:

```
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(16a8.1124): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not  available)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=036a848c edx=00000000 esi=00000003 edi=00000003
eip=7700c7ec esp=00daa5c8 ebp=00daa750 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc:
7700c7ec c21400          ret     14h
```

/SafeMode did not work either.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: in windbg run **!analyze -v** and post the result

Comment: have you tried the update 3 for VS2015?

Comment: I finally got it to reinstall without any updates and now I do not have the problem any more. I will not also install the updates because of "never touch a running system" ;-) So thanks anyway.